# Working with ViewState to maintain property state through postbacks

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate, asp.net-webpages

I know this is a common problem, I have looked around and tried many things but I can't seem to get it to work properly.

I have a dropdown list that lists its elements in ascending order, I added a checkbox that is supposed to reverse the order of the dropdown list.

I am attempting to add a property to the dropdown list control, something along the lines of:

```
    public bool isReverse = false;

    public bool reverse
    {
        get
        {
            return ViewState["isReverse"] != null ? (bool)ViewState["isReverse"] : false;
            //return ViewState["isReverse"] != null ? (bool)ViewState["isReverse"] : isReverse;
//I have also tried returning isReverse, but its the same behaviour
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["isReverse"] = value;
            isReverse = value;
        }

    }
```

There may be redundant code in there. My checkbox has an event handler that does the following:

```
    protected void isReverse_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox myBox = (CheckBox)sender;
        SortableCustomDropDownLIst myList = sddl;
        if (myBox.Checked)
        {
            myList.reverse = true;
        }
        else
        {
            myList.reverse = false;
        }
    }
```

My initial solution was not using ViewState so it was resetting back to false every time we had a postback and it would never list in reverse order. My code checks this property and determines if it needs to reverse the ArrayList responsible for feeding the dropdown list or not.

I am unsure why my program has the following behaviour:

Load Page: Ascending Order, CheckBox unchecked

Check checkbox: Still Ascending Order, CheckBox checked

Uncheck checkbox: Descending Order, CheckBox unchecked

Check checkbox: Ascending Order, CheckBox checked

...repeat.

The sets are only called by the event handler for the checkbox, the get is only called when sorting the dropdown list. Am I misunderstanding something, I can't see why this wouldn't work, unless I am misunderstanding how ViewState works properly.

I think it has something to do with how the first event handle triggers the property to true, however ViewState is not set yet, so it doesn't remember anything.

Comment: This line accomplishes nothing: `SortableCustomDropDownLIst myList = sddl;`   Could that be why things aren't working?

Comment: @SteveWellens Yeah, I will work to remove these things soon. I wasn't sure about something and wrote a lot of nonsense things. I believe that handler is working as what I want it to. Something to do with the property.

Comment: Why not accomplish this in client-side script?

Answer (score 0):

I found out what I was doing wrong.

I was trying to resort/redo my dropdown list in Page_Load, however the property I am supposed to toggle true/false has been not modified yet, as it is done so in the event for the checkbox being clicked.

I moved the function that does the sorting/displaying of the order of the dropdown list to the checkbox event and it now works as intended.